# add delay to DOMMouseScroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some divs which should appear after user's scroll. So I track `mouseScroll` event. But I want to add some delay to my event. I tried to use `setTimeout` but it didn't help... If I do a full scroll of wheel (more than one per act), I get nothing except removing my class `.shown`. What should I do? Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timer;
  var delay = 1000;

  $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    var shown = $(".shown").removeClass('shown');
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 14 || event.originalEvent.detail < 14) {
        // scroll up
        if (shown.next() && shown.next().length) {
          shown.next().addClass('shown');
        } else {
          shown.siblings(":first").addClass('shown');
        }
      } else {
        // scroll down
        if (shown.next() && shown.next().length) {
          shown.next().addClass('shown');

        } else {
          shown.siblings(":first").addClass('shown');
        }
      }
    }, delay);
  }, function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  });
});
```

```css
.view {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
#first {
  background: grey;
}
#second {
  background: red;
}
#third {
  background: blue;
}
#fourth {
  background: orange;
}
#fifth {
  background: green;
}
.view.shown {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="view shown" id="first"></div>
<div class="view" id="second"></div>
<div class="view" id="third"></div>
<div class="view" id="fourth"></div>
<div class="view" id="fifth"></div>
```

Unfortunately, I don't know, also, how to reverse this script with the same delay. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use:

```
  $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    var shown = $(".shown").removeClass('shown');
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 14 || event.originalEvent.detail < 14) {
        // scroll up
        if (shown.next() && shown.next().length) {
          shown.next().addClass('shown');
        } else {
          shown.siblings(":first").addClass('shown');
        }
      } else {
        // scroll down
        if (shown.next() && shown.next().length) {
          shown.next().addClass('shown');

        } else {
          shown.siblings(":first").addClass('shown');
        }
      }
    }, delay);
  });
```

Comment: it works but not as it was expected - if you do a "large" scroll, the system craches. I need changes on "large" scroll... what do I do wrong?...

Comment: what is that mean "large" scroll? Please, show code context. It is probably another reason of crash, not because of scroll.

Comment: the system tracks event "scroll" but when I do another one, it removes class "show" and nothing adds. This code helps with one-by-one scroll, really works. but I have to do a lot in order to improve it. [Fulpage.js](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-yf_E9Z3LAhWrC5oKHc6kCBcQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Falvarotrigo.com%2FfullPage%2F&usg=AFQjCNETe6ZqOIznFqASVcshwcCM10-Tmg&sig2=Rn_My6Km7U-v1vdrE1WfPQ&bvm=bv.115339255,d.bGs) solved my problem and I want to say you "thank you" for your help!